# How to prevent to use specified class/method in code with static analysis tools?

Tags: java, sonarqube, checkstyle

We have many teams with a lot of java code.
For avoiding performance issue, we want to prevent to use some specified classes/methods on many code repositories.

How to prevent to use specified class/method in code with static analysis tools, like CheckStyle, Sonarqube?

Comment: you can mark them with ``@Deprecated``

Comment: Sorry to lack of contexts. Class/method what we want to exclude would be also 3rd party code. We cannot mark with `@Deprecated`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good candidate for Checkstyle's
[IllegalType](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_coding.html#IllegalType) and [IllegalImport](http://https:/https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_imports.html#IllegalImport) checks. Also, for finer granularity, you can use [ImportControl](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_imports.html#ImportControl).

Additionally, in your configuration, you can forbid certain methods as follows, using [MatchXPath](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_coding.html#MatchXpath):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
        "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
        "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <property name="charset" value="UTF-8"/>

    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="MatchXpath">
            <property name="query" value="//METHOD_CALL//DOT[.//IDENT[@text = 'yourForbiddenMethod']]"/>
            <message key="matchxpath.match"
                     value="Avoid using deprecated method 'yourForbiddenMethod()'."/>
        </module>

    </module>
</module>
```

Code example:

```java
public class Test {
    static int method(Object args) {
        return AllowedClass.yourForbiddenMethod(args);
    }
}
```

Result:

```sh
➜  src java -jar checkstyle-8.42-all.jar -c config.xml Test.java
Starting audit...
[ERROR] /src/Test.java:3:29: Avoid using deprecated method yourForbiddenMethod(). [MatchXpath]
Audit done.
Checkstyle ends with 1 errors.
```

Comment: Thank you! Now we are using Checkstyle 7.x. We try this way, also version up.

Comment: You're welcome. If you need more help getting up and running, please add some concrete examples in your post, and I can give more specific configurations for them. Also, you can ask for help on Google groups at https://groups.google.com/g/checkstyle .

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [JArchitect](https://www.jarchitect.com), with cqlinq you can create your custom rules to detect all the uses of specific classes/methods.

Comment: Thank you! First, we try with checkstyle.

Answer (score -1):

You might take a look at [ArchUnit](https://www.archunit.org/). I suspect you could use it to write some unit tests to look for the classes/packages you want to forbid and to throw errors if it encounters them.

You can also write [custom checks for Checkstyle](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/writingchecks.html#Writing_FileSetChecks)

Comment: Thank you! ArchUnit looks it's required to write desired tests on each modules want to check. Custom check for Checkstyle looks easy to apply for us because our modules already depend on same checkstyle definition.

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer is what you want, please 'accept' it.

Comment: @JohnFergus  custom checks aren't necessary in this case, Checkstyle has quite a few existing checks that can be used to accomplish this task.